# Specifing Alias for dll

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have given an alias name to a dll which I am referencing from Visual studio by going to the property of that dll and specifing the alias and using the same in my code file.

```
extern alias toolkitalias;
using toolkitalias::System.Windows;
using toolkitalias::System.Windows.Controls;
```

But still it gives error saying  **The extern alias 'toolkitalias' was not specified in a /reference option"**

Am I missing something. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some research and what I found is giving alias to a dll from Visual studio doesnt work as expected and is reported as a bug.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615953/reference-aliases-are-ignored-on-projects-containing-some-xaml-files.

Also the above solution only works in case code behind files and not in case of xaml. For xaml, what Marc suggested is correct with alias name given from visual studio property window as global,toolkitalias.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell it the alias **against the reference**; in Solution Explorer, find the reference (under "References"), and look in the Properties window. There is an "Aliases" property that defaults to "global". Either change it to your new alias, or append (comma delimited) the alias. So you might change it to either "`toolkitalias`", or "`global,toolkitalias`".

Comment: @Dipesh double-check it; I have a repro here with 2 references, one marked "test0", one marked "global,test1". Then I have 3 extern aliases - for "test0", "test1", and "test2"; the first 2 are fine; the 3rd gives exactly the error message you describe (but for "test2"). Sure it isn't a typo?

Comment: Is the process to set the "aliases" on the reference and then use it?  I'm getting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0432?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0432), so somehow still not defined?

Comment: @CoreyAlix did you include `extern alias foo;` (for your own `foo`) at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes I did. Originally it was not at the top but it then complained.  What I did not do is "compile with the /reference" option as I'm not sure what that means (I'm on .net 4.8) and since I do have control of both dependency projects I can fix it in code.  But still I am curious how to do this.